# Как зайти в аккаунт Google с помощью Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Код пишу на Python.

Задача в том, чтобы с помощью Selenium отслеживать статус работы программы в Google Colab. Но у меня при попытке авторизоваться в Google появляется следующее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, каким образом можно обойти это ограничение?

Comment: Google считает доступ через Python небезопасным и блокирует его. Попробуйте добавить ваш "user agent" при выполнении входа

Comment: И не забывайте, что при таком входе Python, скорее всего, устанавливает http подключение, а оно не шифруется, и ваши данные от аккаунта вполне несложно перехватить. (особенно если злоумышленник подключится к вашей сети)

Comment: @Стас
Подскажите, я добавил следующие строчки в программу:

UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": UA})

Авторизоваться также не получается. Мне необходимо ещё, что-то указать?

Comment: Этого оказалось недостаточно. Почитайте [это обсуждение](https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/51b247080976cb41fe93), там есть вариант, который может сработать. И также они советуют авторизоваться через аккаунт Google, например, в  Stack Overflow (или в любом другом приложении, которое поддерживает авторизацию через Google), и потом этот аккаунт будет использоваться даже после перехода на другой сайт (в том числе сайт Google). Google не считает приложение Stack Overflow небезопасным, и через него можно авторизоваться. Но может уже что-то изменилось, и нужно искать другой путь.

Comment: @Стас "Google не считает приложение Stack Overflow небезопасным, и через него можно авторизоваться." - работает! Это замечательно. Спасибо Вам!
Подскажите, могли бы Вы добавить этот комментарий в качестве ответа на мой вопрос?

Comment: На зарубежном форуме был найден ответ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378197/automating-gmail-login-using-python-selenium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как Python устанавливает HTTP подключение с сервером, Google не разрешает ему авторизоваться (это может быть опасно для ваших данных от аккаунта, когда они передаются в не зашифрованном виде). Далеко не все компании так делают (например, Яндекс не блокирует доступ).

---

И если вы всё же уверены, что вам это нужно - напрямую через Google авторизоваться вряд ли получится. Вы постоянно будете получать ошибку "Этот браузер или приложение небезопасны".

Но это можно обойти. Если вы авторизуетесь в любом приложении, которое считается безопасным и поддерживает вход через аккаунт Google, то вы сможете пройти авторизацию (вход через другие приложения не блокируется даже для небезопасных браузеров). Можно использовать, например, авторизацию через `Stack Overflow`

---

> Ну и зачем мне это приложение? Мне нужен мой аккаунт Google

Когда вы авторизуетесь в приложении, вы также останетесь в своём Google аккаунте, даже когда закроете сайт, через который проходила авторизация. Можете отрыть тот же `google.com` и проверить.

---

Вот простой пример авторизации:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/identifier?client_id=717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile%20email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackauth.com%2Fauth%2Foauth2%2Fgoogle&state=%7B%22sid%22%3A1%2C%22st%22%3A%2259%3A3%3ABBC%2C16%3A9b15b0994c6df9fc%2C10%3A1591711286%2C16%3A66b338ce162d6599%2Ca78a0c663f0beb12c0559379b61a9f5d62868c4fbd2f00e46a86ac26796507a1%22%2C%22cdl%22%3Anull%2C%22cid%22%3A%22717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn.apps.googleusercontent.com%22%2C%22k%22%3A%22Google%22%2C%22ses%22%3A%22921f8f04441041069683cc2377152422%22%7D&response_type=code&o2v=1&as=NCQvtBXI4prkLLDbn4Re0w&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow')
time.sleep(3)
email = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
email.send_keys('LOGIN')

nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
nextBtn.click()

time.sleep(2)
passwd = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passwd.send_keys('PASSWORD')


nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
nextBtn.click()

print("Login completed!")
```

Та длинная ссылка - это страница авторизации через Google от сайта `Stack Overflow`. Вы, скорее всего получите ошибку авторизации на SO (запросы похожи на автоматические), но в аккаунт Google вы всё равно попадёте.

Comment: Спасибо. А то я уже мозгами чуть не ипанулся, хотел лезть выяснять как гугл детектирует селениум, это же обычный хром. Интересно, как?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, Так как Python устанавливает HTTP подключение с сервером, Google не разрешает ему авторизоваться.

Comment: Питон ничего устанавливать не должен, на сайт лезет хром селениума!

Comment: Перестало работать. Есть идеи как это пофиксить?

Comment: На 12.12.2022, этот способ не работает, какие есть еще варианты?

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/

На конец 2021 работает

Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 23.